# Hashlib not encrypting correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, spyder, sha, sha512

I made a little example to show that hashlib is not encrypting correctly! (Background info: the hash for 'e' in SHA512 is "87c568e037a5fa50b1bc911e8ee19a77c4dd3c22bce9932f86fdd8a216afe1681c89737fada6859e91047eece711ec16da62d6ccb9fd0de2c51f132347350d8c")

```
    #imports
import hashlib
#var
code = "87c568e037a5fa50b1bc911e8ee19a77c4dd3c22bce9932f86fdd8a216afe1681c89737fada6859e91047eece711ec16da62d6ccb9fd0de2c51f132347350d8c" #Input decoding string here. this one equals e.
dbanswer = "e"
dbanswer = dbanswer.encode()
dbanswer = hashlib.sha3_512(dbanswer)
dbanswer = dbanswer.hexdigest()
print(dbanswer)
print(code)
```

The output is:
`6ebb8a73bfd0459bd575b9dbef6dcb970bb11182591f5ecd7c8c0d771b3269b715fcb84005d542ff74306565a46b3b893f64ca41b8519457ae137f6429dfbb1e`
`87c568e037a5fa50b1bc911e8ee19a77c4dd3c22bce9932f86fdd8a216afe1681c89737fada6859e91047eece711ec16da62d6ccb9fd0de2c51f132347350d8c`
I am using Python 3.7 on Spyder. Many thanks to someone that can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong hashing algorithm if you want SHA512.

```
import hashlib

def hash_sha512(s):
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    h.update(s.encode())
    return h.hexdigest()

print(hash_sha512('e'))
# 87c568e037a5fa50b1bc911e8ee19a77c4dd3c22bce9932f86fdd8a216afe1681c89737fada6859e91047eece711ec16da62d6ccb9fd0de2c51f132347350d8c
```

`sha3_512` is [the 512 variant of the SHA3 algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SHA-3#/Instances).